# Server Connectivity Issue in Android 10

Tags: android, connection, android-10.0, httpsurlconnection

We are attempting a Server communication with **"HttpsURLConnection"** object, where we have set the "connection" property of the request Object to "close" **[setRequestProperty("Connection", "close")]**. The above setting was working fine until in Android 9 OS in all devices, where as in some of the devices with Android 10 OS(Eg: **Samsung A70 with Android 10**) we are encountering an **"java.net.ConnectException"**. When we remove our Connection property, the server communication got established and resolved the issue. I need your support in understanding the root-cause why there is a behavioral change in Android 10 OS and is there any impact by removing the connection object

```
url = new URL(reqURL);
httpsConnection = url.openConnection();
httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en");
httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/text");
OutputStream os = httpsConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(cvmesgToServer.getBytes()) httpsConnection.connect();
```

Comment: can u post relevant code and stacktrace

Comment: You have not told what the close request does. Or why you would need it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set timeout - Samsung update is bugged as hell

https://www.softax.pl/blog/solved-samsung-a70-problems-after-upgrade-to-android-10-do-i-have-to-wait-for-samsung-to-help-my-app-users/